# SwiftyJSONが読み込めない

Tags: swift, xcode, json

[SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON)を使おうとしています。

githubからzipをダウンロードしました。

1. zipを解凍したSwiftyJSON-masterフォルダをプロジェクトフォルダにコピーします。
2. SwiftyJSON-masterフォルダのSwiftyJSON.xcodeprojをXCodeのプロジェクトにドラッグ＆ドロップします。
3. Build Phases → Target Dependenciesの+をクリックして「SwiftyJSON iOS」を選択しAddを押す。

以下にソースファイル(`ViewController.swift`)を添付しますが、ビルドして実行するとライブラリが読めないというエラーが発生します。

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/SwiftyJSON.framework/SwiftyJSON
  Referenced from: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/68BF78B3-012D-428D-BFCB-77D9201CEA42/tableviewsample002.app/tableviewsample002
  Reason: image not found
```

http://noumenon-th.net/webstrategy/2015/05/22/swiftyjson/ やGitHubのREADME.mdは読んでいます。

XCode 6.4で、iPhone 6で試しています。

```
import UIKit
import SwiftyJSON

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        let url = NSURL(string: "http://www.ubuntu.jp/json.php")
        var request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)

        var data = NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse: nil, error: nil)
        if data != nil {
            var json = JSON(data: data!)
            println(json)
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

このエラーは実行時にフレームワークが見つからなくてロードできなかったということを示しています。

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/SwiftyJSON.framework/SwiftyJSON
 Referenced from: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/68BF78B3-012D-428D-BFCB-77D9201CEA42/tableviewsample002.app/tableviewsample002
Reason: image not found
```

Dynamic Frameworkは実行時にリンクされるので、アプリケーションバンドルに配置されている必要があります。

下記のように、アプリケーションのターゲットのEmbedded Binariesのセクションで「＋」をクリックして、iOS用のSwiftyJSON.frameworkを選択して追加します。

これで、ビルド時にフレームワークがアプリケーションバンドルにコピーされます。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]